# Newbie : Drupal where to find the node target in CMS to edit

Tags: drupal

I have been asked to do a quick edit in a drupal install as a side-side project and I don't know anyhing about Drupal. I found the view and in header section there is custom PHP code listed as follow

```
<div class="hit_us">
<a href="https://website.com/node/add/pagename" id="hit_us">Hit Us</a>
</div>
```

I want to know where can I find the content in node/add/pagename. I just need to change a line of text. I tried looking in content section but there are 1000's of published items and I was not able to find it there.

It is a very basic question but I tried a lot to find but comes up with something else always.

I found out that the pagename is a content type and I found the help text I was looking in manage fields section. So problem solved but thanks guys for taking interest in such a trivial question.

Comment: If you're new to Drupal, the answer to your question might be kind of complex... What part do you want to change? e.g. is it a form field? Help text? Title?

Comment: Your "custom PHP code" is usually called "HTML"

Comment: I want to change a short text description which is part of https://website.com/node/add/pagename

Comment: @AmanAujla Drupal is a dynamic CMS, there isn't an HTML file somewhere with that description in that you can just edit. Do you mean you want to change the description of a content type (article, basic page, etc)? Please be **specific**

Comment: I understand the fact that I am playing with a CMS and am not expecting to find a HTML file laying around somewhere :). I want to know in the UI of CMS where to go to change the help text.

Comment: Are you being this obtuse on purpose?! **WHAT TEXT DO YOU WANT TO EDIT?** I'm not asking for my health, the answer to that question will define the answer to _your_ question :)

Comment: It looks like I am not good at asking questions but I found the texst string that I wanted to change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a folder in the directory sites/all/modules called `stackexample`. Inside
that directory, create two files: `stackexample.info` and `stackexample.module`.

Place the following code inside `stackexample.info`:

```
name = Stack Example
description = Displays a message with form values on pagename nodes.
core = 7.x
```

Place the following code inside `stackexample.module`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function stackexample_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'pagename_node_form') {
    // Trigger a message if arg(3) is set to "showtheform"
    // e.g. node/add/pagename/showtheform
    if (arg(3) == 'showtheform') {
      drupal_set_message('<pre>' . check_plain(print_r($form, 1)) . '</pre>');
    }
    // This example will add a custom title to the revision info area if uncommented
    // $form['revision_information']['#collapsed'] = FALSE;
    // $form['revision_information']['#title'] = t('CUSTOM TITLE FOR REVISION AREA');
  }
}
```

Go to `admin/modules` and enable the `Stack Example` module.

Go to `node/add/pagename/showtheform` to see all the possibilities, and adapt the example
lines as needed.

NOTE: it is not advised to enable this on a production site, because no security measures
are in place and the entirety of the `pagename` form will be exposed to anyone with the
the permission to create a `pagename` node (if they know to add `showtheform` to the url).

HTH.. :)